# View my total YouTube subscribers over time

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to view my total YouTube subscribers over time?

I know the analytics can show you the subscriber change for every day and then I could export the data and calculate the cumulative sum. Is it possible to view in the Analytics page?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube bafflingly doesn't have this feature. You can use socialblade.com and other YouTube statistics pages to view this though.

Comment: afaict socialblade only goes back a few years and doesn't keep track of small channels? it's definitely my go-to source for looking at decently sized channels